# Won't run based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.3

```
a1 = int(0)
a2 = int(0)
b1 = int(0)
b2 = int(0)

while a1 and a2 != 10 or b1 and b2 != 10:
something
```

***Basically the code won't run something, I'm not too sure what's wrong with my While conditions, any ideas?***

Answer (score 4):

```
while a1 and a2 != 10
```

does not check if both a1 and a2 are 10. It is two conditions, `a1` and `a2 != 10`. And `a1` evaluates to `False` since it is 0.

Also, you don't need to say `int(0)`; just `0` is fine.

Comment: To use parenthesis to to remove any ambiguity `while (a1) and (a2 != 10)`.

Comment: I don't really understand. What will be working While statement be then?

Comment: while a1!=10 and a2!=10. And please refer to the 'duplicate' post for a complete explanation.

Comment: Okay, the issue with that is that I need A1 and A2 OR B1 and B2 to be not equal to 10, as the objective of the game is to get the 10.